# Remove documents using datetime object?

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

Trying to pass a datetime object via pymongo, as I can't use a hardcoded "datetime" as shown in all the pymongo documentation (eg: "2015-12-24T11:59:00Z").

Simply want to delete collections over 7 days old. Why is it erroring on "an integer is required" when I'm passing it a UTC date via 'newDate'?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pymongo import MongoClient

newDate = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)
result = db.collection.remove({"receivedDateUtc" : { '$lte' : datetime(newDate) }} )
```

Comment: it is unrelated to pymongo. You would get the same error with just `datetime(datetime.utcnow())` that expects a `year` (an integer) as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `newDate` is already a `datetime` object.

```
result = db.collection.remove({'receivedDateUtc' : { '$lte' : newDate }} )
```

Demo:

```
In [67]: newDate = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)

In [68]: newDate
Out[68]: datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 29, 22, 2, 41, 391369)
```